# How to read file (addressed by URL) into string, in java?

Tags: java, url

This is the code:

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file:/path/my.jar!/META-INF/file.txt");
File file = File.createTempFile("foo", ".txt");
file.deleteOnExit();
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
String txt = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

Can I do the same with less lines of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have apache [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)

```
    URL url = new URL("jar:file:/path/my.jar!/META-INF/file.txt");
    String myString = IOUtils.toString(url);
```