# How to reference one file from another in WEB-INF/classes folder in Tomcat?

Tags: json, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7, properties-file

I have two files (one `.properties` and another `.json`) in my webapps//WEB-INF/classes folder. I need to reference the `.json` file from the `.properties` file. As both are in same location, `propertyName=File.json` should work,but it does not. If I mention the absolute path, it works fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please provide more info on how are you using the .properties file? Also the source code.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is read your File.json exactly the same way as your properties file if you don't want to specify the absolute path.
If propertyName=File.json :

```
String jsonFile = props.getProperty("propertyName");
```

Then you can do the following to have your file as URL object :

```
URL jsonURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(jsonFile);
```

Or as InputStream

```
InputStream jsonStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jsonFile);
```

Depending on what you want to do with it later, once you have your file as InputStream or URL, you can refer to these questions :

- [Read convert an inputstream to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)
- [How to read file addressed by url into string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283778/how-to-read-file-addressed-by-url-into-string-in-java)